# Board game 4 players with 4 colors in C++

Tags: c++

I have been working on a board game in C++ using Qt. The game consists of four players with four different colors.

This is all working fine, but I want to know if there is any other way to do this. Any ideas on how to improve this code and especially ideas on completely different ways to achieve the same are welcome.I want to reform/reduce/imporve the quality of the whole code.

```
    game::game(){
    game_delay = 1000;
    game_complete = false;
    turn_complete = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
         player_positions.push_back(-1);
    }
    color = 3;
}

void game::reset(){
    game_complete = false;
    turn_complete = true;
    for(auto i : player_positions){
        i = -1;
    }
    color = 3;
}


int game::rel_to_fixed(int relative_piece_index){
    return relative_piece_index + color * 4;
}

int game::isStar(int index){
    if(index == 5  ||
       index == 18 ||
       index == 31 ||
       index == 44){
        return 6;
    } else if(index == 11 ||
              index == 24 ||
              index == 37 ||
              index == 50){
        return 7;
    }
    return 0;
}

int game::isOccupied(int index){ //returns number of people of another color
    int number_of_people = 0;

    if(index != 99){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < player_positions.size(); ++i){
            if(i < color*4 || i >= color*4 + 4){        //Disregard own players
                if(player_positions[i] == index){
                    ++number_of_people;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return number_of_people;
}

bool game::isGlobe(int index){
    if(index < 52){     //check only the indexes on the board, not in the home streak
        if(index % 13 == 0 || (index - 8) % 13 == 0 || isOccupied(index) > 1){  //if more people of the same team stand on the same spot it counts as globe
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void game::send_them_home(int index){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < player_positions.size(); ++i){
        if(i < color*4 || i >= color*4 + 4){        //this way we don't skip one player position
            if(player_positions[i] == index){
                player_positions[i] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void game::move_start(int fixed_piece){
    if(dice_result == 6 && player_positions[fixed_piece] < 0){
        player_positions[fixed_piece] = color*13; //move me to start
        send_them_home(color*13); //send pieces home if they are on our start
    }
}

int game::next_turn(unsigned int delay = 0){
    if(game_complete){
        return 0;
    }
    switch(color){
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            ++color;
            break;
        case 3:
        default:
            color = 0;
            break;
    }
    global_color = color;
    rollDice();
    relative.dice = getDiceRoll();
    relative.pos = relativePosition();
    emit set_color(color);
    emit set_dice_result(dice_result);

    msleep(delay);
    switch(color){
        case 0:
            emit player1_start(relative);
            break;
        case 1:
            emit player2_start(relative);
            break;
        case 2:
            emit player3_start(relative);
            break;
        case 3:
            emit player4_start(relative);
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void game::movePiece(int relative_piece){
    int fixed_piece = rel_to_fixed(relative_piece);     //index of the piece in player_positions
    int modifier = color * 13;
    int relative_pos = player_positions[fixed_piece];
    int target_pos = 0;
    if(player_positions[fixed_piece] == -1){        //if the selected piece is in the safe house, try to move it to start
        move_start(fixed_piece);
    } else {
        //convert to relative position
        if(relative_pos == 99){
            std::cout << "I tought this would be it ";
        } else if(relative_pos < modifier) {
            relative_pos = relative_pos + 52 - modifier;
        } else if( relative_pos > 50) {
            relative_pos = relative_pos - color * 5 - 1;
        } else {//if(relative >= modifier)
            relative_pos = relative_pos - modifier;
        }
        if(DEBUG) std::cout << "color: " << color << " pos: " << relative_pos << " + " << dice_result << " = " << relative_pos + dice_result;
        //add dice roll
        relative_pos += dice_result;    //this is relative position of the selected token + the dice number

        int jump = isStar(relative_pos); //return 0 | 6 | 7
        if(jump){
            if(jump + relative_pos == 57){
                relative_pos = 56;
            } else {
                relative_pos += jump;
            }
        }
        //special case checks
        if(relative_pos > 56 && relative_pos < 72){ // go back
            target_pos = 56-(relative_pos-56) + color * 5 + 1; //If the player moves over the goal, it should move backwards
        }else if(relative_pos == 56 || relative_pos >= 99){
            target_pos = 99;
        }else if(relative_pos > 50){ // goal stretch
            target_pos = relative_pos + color * 5 + 1;
        } else {
            int new_pos = relative_pos + color * 13;
            if(new_pos < 52){
                target_pos = new_pos;
            } else { //wrap around
                target_pos = new_pos - 52;  //this is the global position wrap around at the green entry point
            }
        }
        //check for game stuff

        if(isOccupied(target_pos)){
            if(isGlobe(target_pos)){
                target_pos = -1; //send me home
            } else {
                send_them_home(target_pos);
            }
        }
        if(DEBUG) std::cout << " => " << target_pos << std::endl;
        player_positions[fixed_piece] = target_pos;
    }
    std::vector<int> new_relative = relativePosition();
    switch(color){
        case 0:
            emit player1_end(new_relative);
            break;
        case 1:
            emit player2_end(new_relative);
            break;
        case 2:
            emit player3_end(new_relative);
            break;
        case 3:
            emit player4_end(new_relative);
        default:
            break;
    }
    emit update_graphics(player_positions);
}

std::vector<int> game::relativePosition(){
    std::vector<int> relative_positons;
    int modifier = color * 13;

    //from start id to end
    for(int i = color*4; i < player_positions.size(); ++i){
        relative_positons.push_back(player_positions[i]);
    }
    //from 0 to start id
    for(int i = 0; i < color*4; ++i){
        relative_positons.push_back(player_positions[i]);
    }


    for(size_t i = 0; i < relative_positons.size(); ++i){
        if(relative_positons[i] == 99 || relative_positons[i] == -1){
            relative_positons[i] = (relative_positons[i]);
        } else if(relative_positons[i] < modifier) {
            relative_positons[i] = (relative_positons[i]+52-modifier);
        } else if(relative_positons[i] > 50) {
            relative_positons[i] = (relative_positons[i]-color*5-1);
        } else if(relative_positons[i] > modifier) {
            relative_positons[i] = (relative_positons[i]-modifier);
        }
    }
    return std::move(relative_positons);
}

void game::turnComplete(bool win){
    game_complete = win;
    turn_complete = true;
    if(game_complete){
        std::cout << "player: " << color << " won" << std::endl;
        emit declare_winner(color);
    }
}

void game::run() {
    if(DEBUG) std::cout << "color:     relative pos => fixed\n";
    while(!game_complete){
        if(turn_complete){
            turn_complete = false;
            msleep(game_delay/4);
            next_turn(game_delay - game_delay/4);
        }
    }
    emit close();
    QThread::exit();
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the class definition in here. Also given there is absolutely no explanation of the game rules, it's a little hard to understand what this code is meant to be doing.

Comment: The code doesn't compile, no matter which C++ compiler I tried.

Answer (score 2):

This is littered with magic numbers. You have 99, 50 and -1 seeming to be some special out of range value, You have *13 in a lot of places for no very obvious reason. And there's also a 52, which is close enough to 50 to make me wonder if one of them is wrong. And a 56.

Your `isOccupied` function sounds as though it is meant to return a `bool`, but it returns an `int` which could cause confusion.

Not sure what `isGlobe` does, but it made me think you were playing on a 3d board for a while.

Also it is unclear what `isStar` does - it has a lot of magic numbers in it.

There's one comment that implies that one of the colours is green, but you don't name them anywhere else, they're just 0, 1, 2, 3.

Presuming `move_start` sends a piece to the players start position, how is that different to any other move in terms of sending other pieces back to their home (I presume -1 is home).

`isOccupied` and `send_them_home` seem to share quite a lot of code. It's not obvious what the `i < colour * 4 || i >= colour*4 + 4` does though (as an aside, I'd find that easier to read as `not (colour * 4 <= i && i < colour * 4)`

`isOccupied` is a camelCase name and `send_them_home` isn't. You shouldn't mix the two naming conventions if you can avoid it.

Your constructor should use member-wise initialisation.

`nextTurn` only returns a 0 or 1. Should it return a boolean?

I cant find where `turnComplete` is called from, but having `turn_complete` as a member variable and `turnComplete` as a method is likely to cause confusion.